# Multiple elements for a single function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have multiple product images which share the same "base" class (`.billede_wrapper1`, `.billede_wrapper2`), and a single JQuery function.

How do i make `.retslet5` only show, when `.billede_wrapper.5` has mouseover?

Here is the current state of the code, and the example:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6C6Mu/23/)

At the example both of the products have the same classes (`.billede_wrapper`, `.retslet`) they will be (`.billede_wrapper1`, .`retslet1`, `.billede_wrapper2`, `.retslet2`) and so on, on the real page.

The numbers representing the database ID of the product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the child .retslet by using `$(this).find('.retslet')`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.retslet').hide();

    $('.billede_wrap').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).find('.retslet').slideDown("fast");
    });

    $('.billede_wrap').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).find('.retslet').slideUp("fast");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hover` :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.retslet').hide();

    $('.billede_wrap').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('.retslet').slideDown("fast");
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('.retslet').slideUp("fast");
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should look for the div to slideup amoungst the children of the element like this

```
$('.billede_wrap').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).children('.retslet').slideDown("fast");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6C6Mu/28/